# Unresponsive Fade-In Fade-Out in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am implementing a twitter-style follow/unfollow functionality with the following jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $(".follow").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;
        $("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif" >');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){
                $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
                $('#follow'+I).fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('#remove'+I).fadeIn(200).show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have a similar unfollow function. However i have the following problem:

When I have `N` items `{1,2..i.N}` each with `id = followi` and I click on the follow button. I find that some of the items respond while others do not. I suspect it is a pure javascript issue...otherwise i figure none of the buttons would respond at all.

Is it a timing issue...all help is appreciated. Also i'd appreciate it if you could point me to a simpler method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are doing the UI update in your ajax success handler, so the reaction time for the UI updated is based on the speed of the Ajax response. And if the server doesn't return successfully, the UI update won't happen at all.

A simpler method with instant response:

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).delegate(".follow","click",function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;
        $("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif"/>');

        $('#follow'+I).fadeOut(200); // act instantly since we assume it will go well
        $('#remove'+I).fadeIn(200);  // act instantly since we assume it will go well 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: info,
            complete: function(){ //always remove the loader no matter if it goes well or not
                $("#loading").slideUp();
            },
            error: function() {
               //handle error
              $('#follow'+I).fadeIn(200); // correct mistake
              $('#remove'+I).fadeOut(200);  // correct mistake
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: either way you're not going to want to bind something to the "ajaxComplete" event INSIDE an "ajaxComplete" handler. If complete is running, you're already complete, just do it. I doubt you want to wait for the next ajax event to complete.

Comment: I'm guessing there are more surprises hidden in follow.php ;)